# Trying to save my Django Model Formset, keep getting ManagementForm error?

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms, modelform

So, a total Django Model Formset Newb question. I'm trying to save my form and keep getting this error:

```
    ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Here is what I have for my TemplateView:

```
  class AttendanceTemplate(TemplateView):

         template_name = 'attendance/index.html'

         def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
             context = super(AttendanceTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
             instruction = Instruction(self.request.user.username)

                 sections_list = self.request.GET.getlist('sections_list')
                 term = self.request.GET.get('term', instruction.term)

                 enrollments = Enrollment.objects.using('wisp').prefetch_related('profile').filter(section_id__in=['111111'], term=term)

                 attendanceQuery = Enrollment.objects.using('wisp').prefetch_related('student').filter(section_id__in=['111111'], term=term)


        for enrollment in attendanceQuery:
           attendance, created = Attendance.objects.update_or_create(
             section_id=enrollment.section_id,
             term=enrollment.term,
             first_name=enrollment.student.first_name,
             last_name=enrollment.student.last_name,
             email_address=enrollment.student.email_address,
        )

    something = Attendance.objects.filter(section_id__in=['111111'], term=term)

    formset = AttendanceFormSet(queryset=something)

    combined = zip(enrollments, formset)

    context['combined'] = combined

    return context
```

Here is how I'm trying to save the form:

```
def post(self, request):
    formset = AttendanceFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for thing in formset:
            formset = thing.save()
            return render_to_response("template/index.html",{'formset': formset}, RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(error.msg)
```

Here is what I have in my template:

```
            <form method="POST" action="">
               {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for enrollment, form in combined %}
                         <div class="wrapper-formset">
                             <div>
                               {{ form.first_name.value }}
                               {{ form.last_name.value }}
                                {{ form.email_address.value }}
                              </div>
                               <div class="clear-all"></div>
                              </div>
                           {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>
```

Am I saving my form wrong? Maybe my loop is wrong? Also, I'd prefer to print each field out individually, so using the "myform.management_Form" may not work for me? (e.g., myform.management_form.field_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render the forms separately, then you **must** include the management form in your template. The fact that you are zipping your forms makes no difference.

Including the management form is easy, just add `{% formset.management_form %}` to your template.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for enrollment, form in combined %}
    ...
```

For that to work, you'll need to make sure that `formset` is in the template context, for example:

```
    context['formset'] = formset
```

You might find the docs on [using model formsets in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template) useful. It would be a good idea to start with the simplest option, `{{ formset }}`, test it, then gradually customize the template. That makes it easier to debug when stuff goes wrong. At the moment it looks like you have missed out `{{ form.id }}`.

Comment: I'm using a zip function though:   combined = zip(enrollments, formset)

    context['combined'] = combined...and adding it in like this   {{ combined.management_form }} which isn't working

Comment: I can see the `zip()`, but that doesn't make any difference. You must include the management form separately.

Comment: ah ok so I still need to pass the formset seperately via context?

Comment: @Alasdair...I'm now getting this error: MultiValueDictKeyError at /template/
"'form-0-id'" -- what is that about?

Comment: You could pass the management form instead, i.e. `context['management_form'] = formset.management_form`. I passed the formset in my answer because you'll see `{{ formset.management_form }}` in most Django templates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108641/discussion-between-michael-sebastian-and-alasdair).