# Can't get past Django MultiValueDictKeyError on specific form id?

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms, modelform

So, everytime I submit my form, I always get this error

```
     MultiValueDictKeyError at /template/ 'form-21-id'
```

Here is my views.py:

```
class SomeTemplate(TemplateView):

  template_name = 'template/index.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AttendanceTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    instruction = Instruction(self.request.user.username)

    sections_list = self.request.GET.getlist('sections_list')
    term = self.request.GET.get('term', instruction.term)

    enrollments = Enrollment.objects.using('api').prefetch_related('profile').filter(section_id__in=['111111'], term=term)

    attendanceQuery = Enrollment.objects.using('api').prefetch_related('student').filter(section_id__in=['111111'], term=term)
    #logger.error(dir(attendanceQuery))
    #logger.error(attendanceQuery.values())

    for enrollment in attendanceQuery:
        #logger.error(enrollment.student.first_name)
        attendance, created = Attendance.objects.update_or_create(
             section_id=enrollment.section_id,
             term=enrollment.term,
             first_name=enrollment.student.first_name,
             last_name=enrollment.student.last_name,
             email_address=enrollment.student.email_address,
             meeting_date=timezone.now(),
             section_info=3,
        )

    something = Attendance.objects.filter(section_id__in=['111111'], term=term)

    formset = AttendanceFormSet(queryset=something)

    combined = zip(enrollments, formset)

    context['combined'] = combined
    context['formset'] = formset

    return context

def post(self, request):
    formset = AttendanceFormSet(request.POST)
    logger.error(formset.errors)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset = formset.save();
        return render_to_response("template/index.html", {'formset': formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))   

    else:
        return HttpResponse(request.POST)
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
       <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for enrollment, form in combined %}
                   {{ form.id }}
                   {% for hidden in combined %}
                        {{ hidden.hidden_fields }}
                    {% endfor %} 

                    <div class="wrapper-formset">
                        <div>
                           {{ form.first_name.value }}
                           {{ form.last_name.value }}
                           {{ form.email_address.value }}
                         </div>

                          <div class="clear-all"></div>
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
           </form>
```

I've included the following key form properties in my template as well:

- form.id
- management form
- hidden fields

What am I missing? Doing it wrong? DB issue?

Comment: Which line in views.py is throwing the exception? Is it the `context['combined'] = combined` statement? It's always safe to slap a full stack trace on these types of questions.

Comment: How many items are in the queryset `something`?

Comment: @Alasdair a lot more than 21 items I think...

Comment: As I said in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501570/trying-to-save-my-django-model-formset-keep-getting-managementform-error/36501816#36501816), I think you are trying to do too much too soon. Look [at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template), and get the simplest version with `{{ formset }}` working first. Then change to `{% for form in formset %}`. Finally, try your zipped list. When something goes wrong, it will hopefully be much clearer what the problem is.

Comment: hmm ok - I'll give that a whirl, thanks